# Can I direct wire a light with a fused plug?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I would like to add lighting to a built-in bookshelf. Is it possible to cut the plug off of the wires (shown here) [image] and join them in a junction box with a line coming from the switch? I would like to use four of these lights with LED bulbs, so the load will be tiny. It seems like it "should" work, but that's what everyone says just before they burn their house down. I don't know if it makes a difference, but the plugs have fuses. What do you think?

Comment: Why not put an outlet in the "*junction box with a line coming from the switch*"  and plug them into that ?  What fuses are you talking about ?

Comment: This would certainly be a cheap way of doing it compared to putting in properly wired low-voltage LED lighting. Until, of course, you get to that whole "burn the house down" thing you've mentioned.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I'll bet these are like Christmas lights and that you slide back a cover on the plug and find a fuse in there. In my experience when the fuse blows, the whole string has gone and gets replaced instead of replacing the fuse, but it makes you feel good when you buy it thinking "I'll just replace the fuse!".

Comment: Yes, exactly, there is a little slider with a fuse inside the plug. I really wanted to avoid having a big ol' outlet box (or several) with visible wires inside the shelf while still not burning down the house.

Comment: @Macybug Perhaps the question should be "What is the proper way  to add LED cabinet lighting to my bookshelf"  and explain where your bookshelf is and where the electricity source is. *LED strip lights that can be daisy chained together so they only have one plug, plugged into a switched outlet OR a smart outlet is one option*.

Comment: "*My house! Is out of the ordinary,
That's right! Don't wanna hurt nobody,
Some things sure can sweep me off my feet,
Burning down the house*" - Talking Heads

Comment: The daisy chained LED's are a great idea. I've been looking at some options on Amazon. Thanks, Alaska Man. "And you may find yourself in a beautiful house, with a beautiful wife, and you may ask yourself, Well, how do I get this silly cabinet lit?"

Comment: +1 to you both for the Talking Heads references! :D

Comment: On sale for $37.00  as of this posting with the code T6SITKKR  - https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07YTL27SY/?ascsubtag=nu5n5jievmj4nhmrj4fKgYwfb46hfSEY&tag=dealnewscom&camp=1789&creative=9325&m=A1KFVZ15HW0P7T

Answer (score 4):

### You need to learn the marvelous world of low voltage LED strips

Seriously.  You get a common 12 volt UL-listed power supply, and a small junction box to splice, and the world is your oyster.

The strips price out at about $7 *for 16 feet* no kidding.  Not $7/foot, more like 43 cents a foot.

Since you're working entirely in low voltage, you're at basically nil risk of shocking anyone or setting anything on fire.  The installation rules are also VERY relaxed, and there's no problem doing what you want the way you plan to.

Which you cannot do with 120V stuff, by the way.

Comment: Yummy, Low voltage Oysters, they get me wired.